# Advanced Search - no results

Tags: advanced-search

I have an intermittent issue with advanced search giving no results. This seems to only happen in Chrome and looks like it might be something to do with PHP sessions.

On submitting the form, there are no results and the form has the focus on the Complete OR Partial Name field - now empty. No error is logged. It is as though the name field isn't being submitted somehow and the user is being urged to put in a correct name.

If the user logs out and logs in again, it works OK.

Is anybody else getting a similar issue? It's very hard to reproduce, but my user is getting it a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE!

You might get that if you have a mix of http / https and www / no www

Use your browser's developer tools to check what URL's are being accessed under the Network tab. (Ctrl-Shift-E on firefox)

They should all be the same - eg https://example.org/... not a mix of http://example.org, https://www.example.org, http://www.example.org

If that is the problem, check your settings in civicrm.settings.php and at `Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs` and make sure they are consistent.

Comment: Good thought, but no - I've checked and all requests are coming from https:// with no www. Wouldn't that problem affect all users/sessions? This problem is that occasional sessions are getting an error. Other user sessions are not. A user session which has the problem gets it every time. Where I get the error, the query string remains as this once the form is submitted: civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1